# rails 4 ActionView::Template::Error in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two layouts one is `application.html.erb` and other is `post.html.erb` All the pages using the layout application.html.erb except one page that uses post.html.erb

All the pages with `application .html.erb` are working but the page with `post` layout is not working only in production mode.

When I refer `error.log` getting error as

```
    ActionView::Template::Error (Permission denied - /var/rails_apps/domain.com/releases/20131025170245/tmp/cache/assets/production/sprockets/82446875410ad6d3314b2a4bb29a4945):
4:   <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? "Domain - " + yield(:title) : "Domain" %></title>
5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
6:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "post", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
7:   <%= javascript_include_tag "post", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
8:   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
9:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
10: </head>
pp/views/layouts/post.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_layouts_post_html_erb__192281524152602475_69920226629340'
```

I set permission to `0777` so how it is possible. Can anyone help.

Comment: Did you set the permission for the same user which is starting up the process. (EG ssh into the box with "bob" and use "app" in capistrano?)

Comment: I am running it from root user only

Answer (score 2):

I faced same problem with Apache+Passenger and fixed by this:

```
# cd tmp/cache/assets/production
# chown -R nobody:nogroup ./sprockets
# ls -l | grep sprockets
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody nogroup 4096 MM DD HH:MM sprockets/
```